# Creating an M3U8 AES-128 Encrypted Playlist Utilizing Local Content

Tags: m3u8

I'd like to create an M3U8 playlist. I'd like it to reference locally stored encrypted content.

My questions are: Can I reference local filepaths in M3U8? What are recommended tools for creating an M3U8 playlist? Where is some good documentation for the limitations and usage of the M3U8 format?